# If jquery POST to a PHP file will cookies work?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I use jquery for a login, it has the gmail type ajax login affect so the user never actually see the login page they are posting to, on this login backen script I set a cookie to remember a users email address, I am curious if cookies are able to be set if the browser never actually goes to the page, it just post to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the cookie will be set, the browser's navigation isn't involved.  The storing of cookies is implemented in a layer below the browsers handling of HTML rendering and navigation.

Comment: thanks, I had sometrouble with it before so I just assumed it wouldn't work, ill keep working on it

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just because the user doesn't see the page, it was still visited by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, browser sees the login page anyway, it just don't render it on the screen. So you should be able to set cookie/session vars as always.